# Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^'

Tags: php

Está dando esse erro:

> warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in /home/j17oloba/public_html/libs/lib.php on line 536

```
function lib_checkemail($email) 
{
if(preg_match("^[0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.[a-z]{2,3}$", $email, $check)) 
{
```

Comment: Tente colocar sua expressão regular entre os caracteres `//`. Exemplo: `/abc/`.

Comment: Você precisa utilizar delimitadores na sua regex, como o @Oeslei mencionou. Veja se resolve, caso contrário, mencione aqui.

Answer (score 3):

É necessário colocar delimitadores na expressão regular, ficando assim:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.[a-z]{2,3}$/", $email, $check))
```

Um delimitador pode ser qualquer caractere não-alfanumérico e que não seja nem uma barra-invertida `\` e nem um espaço em branco. Exemplos: `/`, `#`, `~`, `%`.

Mais informações: [Delimitadores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa adicionar delimitadores na sua expressão regular.

Exemplo usando um `#` no início e no final:

```
"#^[0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.[a-z]{2,3}$#"
```